# Is there a way to move old log files, from a log4net RollingLogFileAppender into a different folder?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have a rolling file appender configured with this:

```xml
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="appname" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="'.'yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to move the old log files into an "archive" folder, instead of having them moved to the same folder?

Comment: Looking forward to the answer to this question. Would be nice to eliminate some of the clutter. If there's nothing built in though, you could certainly roll your own. It's somewhere on my to-do list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always open RollingLogFileAppender.cs and modify it to anything you want. It's open source, mate. And this class is really easy to extend. Personally I hate its naming style for log files, and I have my own RollingLogFileAppender to please me. :)

Comment: I figured it would have to be something like that. At least it gives me the chance to add some more naming customization as you say.

Comment: Can you provide modified RollingLogFileAppender.cs @Karma_Police